# Line breaks in WhatsApp messages sent with Python

Tags: python, whatsapp, pyautogui

I am making a fairly simple code to send WhatsApp messages through Python and I need to use line breaks.

For example, if the message is "Dear Student, Please send your report Thank you for your attention"

The message on WhatsApp should look like

> Dear Student,
>
> Please send your report
>
> Thank you for your attention

Attempts with \ n have not worked. The text must be in a single message. Below the code that I have advanced, thanks in advance for the help.

```
# Necessary libraries 

import pyautogui as pg
import webbrowser as web
import time    

message = "Dear Student, \n Please send your report\n Thank you for your attention"

number = 'XX_XXXXXXXXX'

web.open("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+number+"&text="+message)

time.sleep(12) # wait for the page to load

pg.click(1335, 690) # click on the submit button location
```

Comment: did you try to insert a <br> in message ?

Answer (score 2):

Use urlencodedtext for the message, because it is a http request,
as so, your message would be

```
Dear%20Student%2C%0APlease%20send%20your%20report%0AThank%20you%20for%20your%20attention
```

[Check this question first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218378/mobile-website-whatsapp-button-to-send-message-to-a-specific-number)

Comment: you can make it as the selected answer. It would be helpful for others who are searching unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2):

- I also had same issue,
- In the WhatsApp web "\n" works as a  key.
- For breaking a line in WhatsApp web you have to use its short keys to break the line.
- Short keys for line break in WhatsApp web are : SHIFT+ENTER
- But if we use it with code then it will hold the 'SHIFT' key during the whole execution. So the text capitalization is going to be change.
- For prevention from capitalization changes you have to send 'SHIFT' key once again to release the 'SHIFT' key.
  So the keys which are going to send by code will be : SHIFT+ENTER+SHIFT

#### You can use any suitable way which will work for you better.

```py
# Necessary libraries 

import pyautogui as pg
import webbrowser as web
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys   
#You have to install selenium for keys or can choose any other library.

message = "Dear Student," + (Keys.SHIFT)+(Keys.ENTER)+(Keys.SHIFT) + "Please send your report" + (Keys.SHIFT)+(Keys.ENTER)+(Keys.SHIFT) + "Thank you for your attention"

number = 'XX_XXXXXXXXX'

web.open("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+number+"&text="+message)

time.sleep(12) # wait for the page to load

pg.click(1335, 690) # click on the submit button location
```

#### Maybe following method will also work for you.

```py
# Necessary libraries 

import pyautogui as pg
import webbrowser as web
import time    

message = """Dear Student,                \
Please send your report          \
Thank you for your attention"""

# In the above just use '\' which is used for concatenation.
# But you have to give extra spaces as I have mentioned.
# because '\' will add only 2 tab spaces in the message during writing.

number = 'XX_XXXXXXXXX'

web.open("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+number+"&text="+message)

time.sleep(12) # wait for the page to load

pg.click(1335, 690) # click on the submit button location
```

#### Update : Must use this following way

- The above messages looks too complicated to type.
- So you can use that in following simple way by assigning the keys in a variable to use simply

```py
import pyautogui as pg
import webbrowser as web
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys   
#You have to install selenium for keys or can choose any other library which be suitable for you.

br = (Keys.SHIFT)+(Keys.ENTER)+(Keys.SHIFT)
message = "Dear Student," + br + "Please send your report" + br + "Thank you for your attention"

number = 'XX_XXXXXXXXX'

web.open("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+number+"&text="+message)

time.sleep(12) # wait for the page to load

pg.click(1335, 690) # click on the submit button location
```

#### Or can try using f or .format string to make it simple.

```py
import pyautogui as pg
import webbrowser as web
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys   
#You have to install selenium for keys or can choose any other library which be suitable for you.

br = (Keys.SHIFT)+(Keys.ENTER)+(Keys.SHIFT)
message = f"Dear Student,{br}Please send your report{br}Thank you for your attention"
####################### Or #########################
# message = "Dear Student,{0}Please send your report{0}Thank you for your attention".format(br)

number = 'XX_XXXXXXXXX'

web.open("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone="+number+"&text="+message)

time.sleep(12) # wait for the page to load

pg.click(1335, 690) # click on the submit button location
```

- Can read my another answer in following link for more info about WhatsApp web using python.
- [How do I read whatsapp messages from a contact using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65299796/how-do-i-read-whatsapp-messages-from-a-contact-using-python/68288416#68288416)
- I am developing WhatsApp bot using python.
- For contribution you can contact at : **anurag.cse016@gmail.com**
- Please give a star on my https://github.com/4NUR46 If this Answer helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pywhatkit, It is easier, you save some steps

```
import pywhatkit as kit
import time

#phones
contacts = ['+-----']


message = "\"⚠️ IMPORTANT ⚠️\n\nToday is friday\""

start_time = (11, 00)  #  11:00 AM

# send
for contact in contacts:
    kit.sendwhatmsg(contact, message, start_time[0], start_time[1])
```